# iOS skobbler updateAnnotation: method distorts annotation image size

Tags: ios, ios8, xcode6, skmaps

I have custom annotations with different `imagePaths` but the same `imageSize` = 64. I don't use `SKAnnotationView` class for some reasons.
So if I add a new annotation with `addAnnotation:withAnimationSettings:`, the image size is 64. But when I'm updating the annotation, the image becomes 32.

Why `updateAnnotation:` method distorts image size? Annotation's `imageSize` property doesn't change and is equal to 64.

P. S. `SKAnnotationView` class works fine, but I really can't use it.

Comment: We're looking into it...

Comment: Thanks Bogdan. The fix will be available in the 2.4 version (few weeks away). Please note that for 2.4 you should add annotations using an SKAnnotationView object, because the imagePath property will be marked as deprecated and it will be removed entirely from the SDK.